Add a given value from a column based on the value from another column
I'm trying to generate a cars sales report using T-SQL.
The report must be grouped and ordered by Customer and Period (format M/yyyy)
The report result table must have the following columns:

Customer: The customer who bought the vehicle.
Period: the date of sale.
Cars quantity: The quantity of vehicles sold for that customer in that period, which type is Car.
Cars total price: The sum of the prices of vehicles (with Car type) sold to that customer in that period.
Trucks quantity: the quantity of vehicles sold for that customer in that period, which type is Truck.
Trucks total price: the sum of the prices of vehicles (with Truck type) sold to that customer in that period.

You can find the SQL scripts I used to create and seed the database as well as the query I'm using here: https://dbfiddle.uk/wxFrkPuK
Here's the query I'm using in attempt to generate the report:
SELECT 
    c.Name_Customer AS 'Customer', 
    FORMAT(v.Sell_Date, 'M/yyyy') AS 'Period',
    CASE 
        WHEN t.Name_Vehicle_Type = 'Car' 
            THEN (COUNT(v.ID_Vehicle)) 
            ELSE NULL 
    END AS 'Cars quantity',
    CASE
        WHEN t.Name_Vehicle_Type = 'Car' 
            THEN SUM(v.Sell_Price) 
            ELSE NULL 
    END AS 'Cars total price',
    CASE 
        WHEN t.Name_Vehicle_Type = 'Truck' 
            THEN (COUNT(v.ID_Vehicle)) 
            ELSE NULL 
    END AS 'Trucks quantity',
    CASE
        WHEN t.Name_Vehicle_Type = 'Truck' 
            THEN SUM(v.Sell_Price) 
            ELSE NULL 
    END AS 'Trucks total price'
FROM
    Customer AS c, Vehicle AS v, Vehicle_Type AS t
WHERE 
    c.ID_Customer = v.ID_Customer 
    AND v.ID_Vehicle_Type = t.ID_Vehicle_Type
GROUP BY 
    v.ID_Customer, FORMAT(v.Sell_Date, 'M/yyyy'), 
    c.Name_Customer, v.ID_Customer, t.Name_Vehicle_Type
HAVING 
    (t.Name_Vehicle_Type = 'Car' OR t.Name_Vehicle_Type = 'Truck')
ORDER BY  
    c.Name_Customer, 'Period'

Here's what I get when running the query:



Customer
Period
Cars qnt
Cars total price
Trucks qnt
Trucks total price




Jane Doe
2/2023
2
53000.00
NULL
NULL


Jane Doe
2/2023
NULL
NULL
2
380000.00


Jane Doe
4/2023
2
27000.00
NULL
NULL


Jane Doe
4/2023
NULL
NULL
2
137990.00


Jason St
5/2023
2
72500.00
NULL
NULL


Jason St
5/2023
NULL
NULL
2
330000.00


Jason St
8/2023
1
25000.00
NULL
NULL


Jason St
8/2023
NULL
NULL
1
57990.00


Mike Fen
6/2023
3
93500.00
NULL
NULL


Mike Fen
6/2023
NULL
NULL
2
330000.00



But I was expecting to receive:



Customer
Period
Cars qnt
Cars total price
Trucks qnt
Trucks total price




Jane Doe
2/2023
2
53000.00
2
380000.00


Jane Doe
4/2023
2
27000.00
2
137990.00


Jason St
5/2023
2
72500.00
2
330000.00


Jason St
8/2023
1
25000.00
1
57990.00


Mike Fen
6/2023
3
93500.00
2
330000.00



Can you see the problem? It's generating an extra line with NULL values in certain cells. I wish to mix the two lines grouping by the customer and period as shown above.

Rather than sharing a file via google drive and asking us to access something that is potentially insecure, create a DBFiddle with the same data and your attempt. Then all someone has to do is tweak the fiddle to provide you an answer.

FYI there is no concept of a cell in a database... that is a spreadsheet thing

Note for you fiddle, ensure it is a [mre] with emphasis on minimal i.e. the bare minimum required to demonstate the issue.

Thank you. I'm going to edit my question

Bad habits to kick: using old-style JOINs - that old-style comma-separated list of tables style was replaced with the proper ANSI JOIN syntax in the ANSI-92 SQL Standard (more than 30 years!! ago) and its use is discouraged

Also - the HAVING clause should only be applied to aggregated columns - which is not the case in your example. This should really be a WHERE clause instead

You need to remove Name_Vehicle_Type from the grouping, and instead use conditional aggregation.
Also:

Use explicit join syntax, not comma-joins, as this is much clearer and less prone to mistakes.
Use [] to quote column names, not ''.
ELSE NULL is not actually necessary, it's the default.
Use EOMONTH to group by month, not FORMAT as the strings don't sort properly and it's slow.
IN is shorter than OR although it compiles to the same thing.
Only aggregation filters should go in HAVING, otherwise use the WHERE. The server can usually push it through to the lower level, but it's best to be explicit.

SELECT
  c.Name_Customer AS Customer,
  EOMONTH(v.Sell_Date AS Period,
  COUNT(CASE WHEN t.Name_Vehicle_Type = 'Car'   THEN 1 END) AS [Cars quantity],
  SUM  (CASE WHEN t.Name_Vehicle_Type = 'Car'   THEN v.Sell_Price END) AS [Cars total price],
  COUNT(CASE WHEN t.Name_Vehicle_Type = 'Truck' THEN 1 END) AS [Trucks quantity],
  SUM  (CASE WHEN t.Name_Vehicle_Type = 'Truck' THEN v.Sell_Price END) AS [Trucks total price]
FROM Customer AS c
JOIN Vehicle AS v ON c.ID_Customer = v.ID_Customer
JOIN Vehicle_Type AS t ON v.ID_Vehicle_Type = t.ID_Vehicle_Type
WHERE t.Name_Vehicle_Type IN ('Car', 'Truck')
GROUP BY
  c.ID_Customer,
  c.Name_Customer,
  EOMONTH(v.Sell_Date)
ORDER BY
  c.Name_Customer,
  EOMONTH(v.Sell_Date);

